# How to define a css rule to find first last in a group of class

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup structure. It has group of *tr* with the same class like grp320, grp321 and grp322.

```
    <tr class="grp320"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp320"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp320"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>

    <tr class="grp321"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp321"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp321"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>

    <tr class="grp322"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp322"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp322"><td colspan="8">Some Data</td></tr>
```

How I can define a CSS rule to apply style having group by CSS class and *first* *last* pseudo element.

Want to add border in between tr's with the same CSS class.

Is this possible with css only or I have to change the markup ?

**Edit:** Is it possible to define a css rule with a wildcard selector like `tr[class^=grp]` unlike defining all *.grp_* classes ?

**Clarification** : I want to add a border bottom to each row of group(.grp_) excluding the first and last item(tr) of group.

Comment: You want the border to be in the first and last instance of each `grp`?

Comment: The semantic way is to change the markup. Put each group of similar tr's in a tbody. If that's possible, by all means do so. Otherwise it gets messy, with selectors like `.grp320 + .grp320, .grp321 + .grp321, .grp322 + .grp322`, `.grp320 + .grp321, .grp321 + .grp322, .grp322:last-child` and so on.

Comment: @Swellar I want to add border in-between rows of first and last.

Comment: @MrLister What if the Markup is not in my control. Is it possible to use css wildcard selectors like `tr[class^=grp]` or something like that so I Don't have to define all grp css classes.

Comment: It is unclear which different tr's you want to target specifically. As the confusion in the answers shows, you have not provided enough information to come up with a clear answer. Please explain better what you need to do, how many tr's there are in the table etc.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible to target all tr's with `tr[class^=grp]`" is yes, but then you're not differentiating between then. That's the same as writing `tr`, at least if there are all the tr's in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The question is still not too clear, but do you mean this?

```css
table {
  border-spacing:0;
}
tr[class^='grp']:not(:first-child) td {
  border-top: 1px solid
}
table .grp320 + .grp321 td, 
table .grp321 + .grp322 td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="grp320"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp320</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp320"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp320</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp320"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp320</td></tr>

    <tr class="grp321"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp321</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp321"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp321</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp321"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp321</td></tr>

    <tr class="grp322"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp322</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp322"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp322</td></tr>
    <tr class="grp322"><td colspan="8">Some Data in grp322</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below:

```
table tr.grp322:last-child td {color:#f00;}
```

or

```
table tr.grp322:last-child {rules here}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    you can write css like below:
     tr:nth-child(3n+1){
          border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     }
      tr:nth-child(3n+3){
          border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

Comment: here you assume they will be always 3 for each class

Comment: There can be any number of tr with each class tr count 3 is not fixed.

Comment: @Mayank That information belongs in the question. You start with "I have the following markup structure", which leads us to believe that you have a table with 3 groups of 3 tr's. If that isn't the case, then say so!